# Why there are black spot on the mesh

Tags: normals

I have tried Flip Normals ctrl+N and recalculate normals but the spots not going all the way. How to get the clean faces. Any suggestion

[image]

[image]

Comment: check doubles, hidden faces, non planars... the usual.

Comment: @m.ardito I have check. Well the file is attach now plz go through. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks perfect here, I have a smooth surface, no black spots...

[image]

but using 3d print analysis tools, there are at least a few non planar faces:

[image]