# How To fix this weird shading issue?

Tags: shaders, subdivision-surface

[image: )[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dUk6.png)

Weird Shading which also effects the sub d in a weird way. Maybe it's a bug but I have a feeling I screwed up somewhere :)

Comment: Ctrl+n in edit mode. Make check your normals. Else remove doubles...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there are black spot on the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80964/why-there-are-black-spot-on-the-mesh) and [Strange shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70209/strange-shading) and [why are some faces of my mesh daker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)...  and many more. Please use the search box at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Go into edit mode, select the entire mesh, and then press Ctrl + N to recalculate the normals.

Comment: Thanks man works perfectly!

Comment: If this fixed your problem, please mark it as answered so other people won't have to waste their time here.